# What happens if your server does XHR to itself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I was digging into server side rendering with Angular this week. It seems architected to be totally isomorphic, so if you are getting data on the server or the client, it's the same line of code that runs. Therefore it would make a call like `this.http.get('http://www.example.com/myurl');` where `this.http` would be an instance of `Http` from `@angular/http`.

On the client side, this is super clear. It means the browser is making an XHR request to my server.

On the server side... what is actually happening behind the scenes? I imagine the node server, being completely unaware of its domain, will make a regular http request, with DNS lookup and everything, just to find itself?

Is that accurate?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The client will make an HTTP request to the server. The server intercepts the request and sends a reply accordingly.

Comment: I think you will get the page HTML as a response

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. The node server would simply make a new HTTP request to `${req.protocol}://${req.headers.host}/your/relative/route` not even knowing that it was going to end up making the request to itself.

Comment: @Booster2ooo, yes when the code is run on the client, that is what happens. I am wondering when my node express server is running a line of code that makes an  XMLHTTPRequest, is it actually just going out to the internet and back via DNS?

Comment: @idbehold any supporting docs? Or is this common sense, like I was thinking? Overall, I'm wondering what kind of weird performance hit that is, to go out to go back to yourself :) Other frameworks I've looked at, I could get the data differently on server than on client, thus ignoring this issue. ie making a db call and populating state rather than making an api call either way

Comment: The question boils down to, how is `XMLHttpRequest` implemented in node.js? IE, if nodejs sees the code `new XMLHttpRequest(...)` what will it do? I believe the answer is: node will fail as `XMLHttpRequest` is not actually part of its runtime, but I may be off-base here.

Comment: @DaveStein if the server makes a new request, then yes, a new HTTP "cycle" begins. What is the host in the request made by the server to itself ?

Comment: @DaveStein *is it actually just going out to the internet and back via DNS?* If you make a request to [`http://localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), everything about the request will happen on the same *computer*.

Comment: No docs specific to angular (I'm a little more familiar with React TBH), but at least that's the way I've seen it structured in isomorphic react/redux applications. The annoying part is that most example isomorphic apps like that all try to simply ignore this common use-case by having all their API endpoints hosted on different domains, thus making the relative route problem just disappear (at least in their examples... sigh).

Comment: @Idbehold yah I actually updated my question to have the full domain. Cause even if you pass relative they usually do some magic like you showed, using the host as the domain. So really it's always getting a domain and then making that external request... to itself.

Answer (score 0):

All comments point to the answer of the question being that your server will reach out for DNS call to come back and hit itself.

Since I was curious about this to know about performance, I did a test like this: `time curl -v http://[mydomain].us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/testedself`.

The endpoint is just an express endpoint with `res.send('Hello World');`. The extra time is ~10MS in this specific test.